# C4272 Error when using QT3D library in visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt3d

i am using microsoft visual studio 2010 for developing an application. Additionally I am using the QT3D library as an external library.

The QT 3D library is sucessfuly installed and integrated with visual studio. I know this because I can compile and run the examples.

but when I try to write my own code, the visual studio compiler gives me the following error

```
 c4272 : 'function' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
```

The error message is received a few hundred times, for each of the member functions which are present in the classes in the library header files.

I suspect, that problem has something to do with the linking of the libraries. In the Additional include files the Path is given as follows

```
"$(QTDIR)\include";"$(QTDIR)\include\Qt3D";"$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui";"$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore";".moc\debug_shared";$(QTDIR)\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

When I iclude the header files, the auto complete option can detect these libraries.

the additional library file paths are given as follows.

```
$(QTDIR)\lib;C:/qt/5.0.1-x64/qtbase/lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

any ideas?

Best Regards
tdk.

Comment: ok so the c4272 error is gone. I still didnt understand the concept behind it, but I changed the /clrpure tp /clr in project properties in general. but now I am getting more errors, 

basically warning C4561: the visual studio documentation is unclear because I have no line which has a __fastcall function calling.

Comment: Not using any of the microsoft windows project templates helped. :) But I will like to know why it reports with an error feedback.